# Data not insert in MySQL databae

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I'm Try to connect with MySQL database with qt by using this code. I'm successfully Build the MySQL plugin for Qt.  But when I try insert data QT it display message box data not inserted. Is any problem with query or something?
This is register.h

```
#ifndef REGISTER_H
#define REGISTER_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QMessageBox>

namespace Ui {
class Register;
}

 class Register : public QDialog
  {
   Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit Register(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
~Register();

 private slots:
   void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
  Ui::Register *ui;
   QSqlDatabase database;
}; 

 #endif
```

and this is register.cpp

```
    #include "register.h"
#include "ui_register.h"

Register::Register(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Register)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Register::~Register()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Register::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //database connection
    database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    database.setHostName("localhost");
    database.setUserName("root");
    database.setPassword("");
    database.setDatabaseName("electricity");

    if(database.open()){

                QString username = ui ->lineEdit ->text();
                QString password = ui ->lineEdit_2 ->text();
                QString fullname = ui ->lineEdit_3 ->text();
                QString adress = ui ->lineEdit_4 ->text();
                QString telephone = ui ->lineEdit_5 ->text();


                // insert query
                QSqlQuery qry;

                qry.prepare("INSERT INTO user_reg_elec (username, password, fullname, address, teli)"
                            "VALUES (:username, :password, :fullname, :adress, :telephone)");

                qry.bindValue(":lineEdit", username);
                qry.bindValue(":lineEdit_2", password);
                qry.bindValue(":lineEdit_3", fullname);
                qry.bindValue(":lineEdit_4", adress);
                qry.bindValue(":lineEdit_5", telephone);

                if(qry.exec()){

                QMessageBox::information(this, "Data Insetrted", "Data Enter sucess");
                }

                else {
                            QMessageBox::information(this, "Data not inserted", "Not Sucessfully");
                }


    }
                else{

                QMessageBox::information(this, "ERROR","Database Not Connected Sucessfully. Please CheckYyour Internet Connection");


}


}
```

I got This [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2wHq.jpg). Is anything have to modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong names to bind to

```
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO user_reg_elec (username, password, fullname, address, teli)"
                        "VALUES (:username, :password, :fullname, :adress, :telephone)");

qry.bindValue(":lineEdit", username);
```

should be

```
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO user_reg_elec (username, password, fullname, address, teli)"
                        "VALUES (:username, :password, :fullname, :adress, :telephone)");

qry.bindValue(":username", username);
```

etc. etc.

The name used in `bindValue` should match the name used in the query.

Comment: after modified,  It should be qry.bindValue(":qstring name", query name)?  I got same error.

Comment: @GeoTech Post your latest code, and I'll take another look.